# Prevent parent view from receiving touch event after child view acts on it

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having a trouble with the responder chain of events on an iOS app.

The problem is the following, I have a set of subviews (bubbles) on a bigger view (square) and I want to be able to show a certain view if I tap on the buttons, however if I tap anywhere else I want the same view to hide.

The problem is when I tap a bubble, both views (child and parent) are triggering, how can I prevent this?

If the child already acted on a touch event shouldn't that be the end of it?

My Bubbles are recognizing the Tap gesture with UITapGestureRecognizer while the parent view (square) uses touchesBegan: method

This graph explains my current setup with multiple bubbles:

[image]

Code:

```
@implementation Bubble
...
-(id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleFingerDTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTap];

}

-(void) handleSingleTap {
NSLog(@"Bubble tapped, show the view");
}
```

for Square

```
@implementation Square
...
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSLog(@"square touched, lets hide the view");
}
```

After a Tap I see both NSLogs on the console

Comment: @LithuT.V code sample included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found what the problem is. UIView inherits from UIResponder, and basic touch events are detected by the view that triggers the touches began events. The subviews that you added in the main view also responds to the touches began method.Thats very basic. You have also added a selector method with tap gesture recognizer. So any touch on bubbles trigger both the methods and hence the two logs. Try adding another gesture recognizer to the view with another selector, like

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnBubble)];
    [self.bubbleView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnMainView)];
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap2];


-(void)tappedOnMainView
{
    NSLog(@"touched on main View");
    [self.vwToShow setHidden:NO];
}
-(void)tappedOnView
{
    NSLog(@"tapped on bubbleview");
    [self.vwToShow setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well , that is the problem . `touchesBegan` will get all the touches , including the ones taken  by the gesture recognizer. You can try to set `gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = TRUE` or use touchesBegan for your bubbles too.

Since it seems that you are making a game here , are you using some engine like cocos2D ? 
If that's the case , there are easier ways to accomplish what you want.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

EDIT:

If you are using only gesture recognizers , the touch will not be sent to the next view in the hierarchy. I think this is what you want. If you decide to go with touches began I think you should do something like this:

//in the bubble view class

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    if(theTouchLocation is inside your bubble)
    {
        do something with the touch
    }
    else
    {
        //send the touch to the next view in the hierarchy ( your large view )
       [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
       [[self nextResponder] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer! I think I could also change the Square to use the gesture recognizer tap, however is there a way to stop the event from passing to the nextResponder from the bubble??

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
@implementation Square{

 ...
 -(id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleFingerDTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTap];

 }

 -(void) handleSingleTap {
   NSLog(@"Sqaure tapped, hide the view");
 }

}
```

Comment: They are not buttons :) they are custom UIView's

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a tap gesture recogniser on the main view as well? Touches began is like writing your own gesture recogniser, but much harder. With multiple tap recognisers, only one will fire.

Comment: Do I need to require the Square recognizer to fail from the bubbles or backwards ?

Comment: @PERR0_HUNTER Sometimes it's quicker to just try it yourself instead of waiting for someone else to tell you.